# elisp difference between emacs 23 and 24, or something else

Tags: emacs, elisp

my previous fine key binding for cscope on emacs 23:

```
(define-key global-map [(control ,)]  'cscope-pop-mark)
```

now got an error on emacs 24

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax ")")
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<3>> nil "/home/ted/.emacs.d/ted.el" nil t)  ; Reading at      buffer position 12743
```

I try to evaluate in in *scratch*, then the following error, but emacs 23 returned ok:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax ")")
  read(#<buffer *scratch*>)
  preceding-sexp()
  eval-last-sexp-1(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp()
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
```

Comment: Try `(global-set-key [control ","] 'cscope-pop-mark)` instead

Comment: What is your question?  Yes, it changed.  Yes, it's documented.  http://repo.or.cz/w/emacs.git/blob/HEAD:/etc/NEWS#l1939

Comment: @triplee Seems not easy to find this. Thanks for the info.

Comment: C-h N displays the NEWS file.

Comment: very handy. After a skim through, a lot doesn't make sense to me yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's fill in the relevant part of the comment pointed at by tripleee:

Another cause of trouble is vector notation
for key sequence notation: instead of [(control ,)] and [(control ')],
you should write [(control ?,)] and [(control ?')], which will work in
older Emacsen too.

Comment: [(control ?,)]  The "?" seems weird though. Does it means escape the following charcter?

Comment: Sort of.  It's a character (as opposed to string) notation.

Comment: @TedFeng `?` denotes a character, which is in Emacs Lisp [nothing more than an integer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Type.html). `?,` is a way of spelling 44, sort of like `','` in C. So `[(control \,)]` and `[(control ?,)]` create two different vectors: the former consists of a two-element list of the symbol `control` and the symbol `,`, while the latter consists of a two-element list of the symbol `control` and the integer 44. Both should be accepted by `define-key`.

Answer (score 0):

It's `[(control ,)]` that is invalid syntax in Emacs 24. Spell it as `[(control \,)]` and the error will disappear with no change to the meaning and no loss of compatibility with older Emacsen.

Comment: Where is this specified in emacs user documentation?

Comment: @TedFeng I don't know about user documentation, but the [symbol type section](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Type.html) of the elisp manual specifies that, other than digits, letters, punctuation, and the characters `_~!@$%^&:<>{}?`, "Any other characters may be included in a symbol's name by escaping them with a backslash. In contrast to its use in strings, however, a backslash in the name of a symbol simply quotes the single character that follows the backslash."